# Jquery - Break/Prevent each loop

Tags: jquery, html

My code is supposed to place a banner between a content, but it is looping the banner. I need it to display a single banner only. I have tried using `return false;`, like the example, but it didn't work:

```
$(".newsitem_text").contents().each(function () {

    if (this.nodeType != 3) {
        newHtml += this.outerHTML;
        count += $(this).text().trim().split(/\s+/).length;
    } else {
        var wordList = $(this).text().trim().split(/\s+/);

        $.each(wordList, function (index, word) {
            count++;
            check();
            newHtml += ' ' + word;
        })
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: did u read the post? lol

Comment: Yes, you need to use `return false;` from the `each` callback

Comment: Why did u mark it as duplicate? I couldn't find the answer in another topic. The `return false` ain't working

Comment: Didn't I say, you should `return false` from the `each` which you want to break. Use this in inner each. Let me know if that work

Comment: But that's what I'm doing, just look at the code, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Okay, create live example with complete code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sure, just a second.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/714Lmgfu/3/

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/714Lmgfu/4/

Comment: Even though it worked, the image should be put after a number of words, and it is being inserted after the content now...

Comment: sorry, looks like I did something wrong when I pasted the fiddle

Comment: Wait, it's correct. Did you remove the `.contents()`?

Comment: Yes, Glad to help :)

Comment: Thank you, but the count is compromised.

Comment: What is count? How it is calculated?

Comment: ` function check() {
        if (count >= 20) `

Comment: Repeat _"What is count? How it is calculated?"_

Comment: It counts 20 words, then add the banner after these 20 words. It is calculated by `function check()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See explanation inline in the code

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6k8cfz7j/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var img = '<img src="http://blog.leadlovers.com.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/23/2014/03/marca21-160x160.png" />'

  // For each element having class
  $(".newsitem_text").html(function(i, h) {
    // h is the oldHTML of the current element

    // h.split(/\s+/).slice(0, 20).join(' ') ==> will get the first twenty words
    return h.replace(h.split(/\s+/).slice(0, 20).join(' '), function(m) {
      // Replace the first 20 words by 20 words followed by image
      return m + img;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:450px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" class="newsitem_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque urna eu pulvinar maximus. Sed elit nunc, vestibulum ut eros vitae, pellentesque rhoncus ipsum. In et metus non diam porttitor maximus iaculis nec lectus. Quisque sodales scelerisque
  auctor. Nam rutrum venenatis eros, eu condimentum erat placerat ut. Pellentesque sed tempus sem, eu viverra ipsum. Vestibulum nec turpis convallis, dapibus massa vitae, posuere mauris. Suspendisse mattis tincidunt lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam
  at tincidunt erat, maximus laoreet ipsum. Quisque nunc neque, semper tincidunt placerat eget, blandit a ante. Suspendisse pulvinar, velit eu ultrices pulvinar, lacus sapien tincidunt ipsum, eget sollicitudin mauris eros molestie ex. Etiam quis orci
  dui. Phasellus vestibulum mollis molestie. Nam condimentum ornare nisl, sed finibus risus tempus vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum eget ullamcorper
  lorem. Aliquam mollis elit in sem dapibus dapibus. Proin vel massa a arcu dictum tincidunt in ut ante. Sed feugiat tempus dictum. Praesent in leo ullamcorper, sodales turpis et, vehicula tellus. Duis pellentesque dui ac turpis tristique imperdiet. Sed
  sed orci lectus. Suspendisse non egestas sem, sed tincidunt sem. Etiam laoreet dui sem. Mauris hendrerit massa tempus, euismod arcu sit amet, eleifend quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus
  id fringilla mauris. Cras dapibus non lacus at finibus. Nullam vitae sagittis neque. Mauris libero velit, interdum non vehicula non, lacinia non augue. Maecenas elementum lacinia interdum. Morbi eget mollis nisl. Integer accumsan condimentum tellus,
  lacinia pellentesque urna volutpat a. Nullam semper sem et erat commodo sollicitudin. Proin rhoncus felis eu aliquam venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla pretium velit eu molestie
  condimentum. Vestibulum vitae velit mi. Integer nec leo quam. Nam pulvinar ligula congue consectetur tristique. Donec placerat faucibus diam sit amet fermentum. Ut id pellentesque risus. Nunc lacus orci, rhoncus ut risus sed, mattis posuere tellus.
  Nulla pellentesque eros sed neque consectetur dictum.</div>
```

Comment: I tested the code, it is working here, but not in my website: http://lucrebem.com.br/blog/emponline/47-ganhe-dinheiro-atraves-de-downloads

Comment: I'm on chat, but I'll have to go soon, it's almost 5 AM.

Comment: @MatheusLopes Make sure you've wrapped the code in `ready` handler. Also check console for errors

Comment: I tried `$(document).ready(jQuery(function ($) {` and it worked on local server, but not in the site.